# Stored Procedure Can't drop temp table it don't exist

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables

SQL Server 2008

This is a continuation of my last question. Now I'm trying to create a stored procedure, however I can't execute it.  When I execute it, an error message displays
"Cannot drop the table #MyReport", because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Below is my stored Procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEL_MyReport]
(
    @employeeid int,
    @date1 datetime,
    @date2 datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
 drop table #MyReport
    Create Table #MyReport
            ( 
                employeeid int,
                name varchar(30), 
                department varchar(30),
                checkTime datetime             
            )    

if (@employeeid > 0)
    Begin
        INSERT INTO #MyReport (employeeid,name, department, checkTime)
           select emp.EmpolyeeID, emp.Name,dep.DeptName,tm.checkTime 
                from TimeInOut tm
                left join Employee emp on emp.EmpolyeeId =   tm.EmployeeId
                left join Department dep on dep.DeptID =  emp.defaultDeptID
                where (DATEDIFF(s,@date1,tm.checktime) >=0 
                and DATEDIFF(s,@date2,tm.checktime)<=0) and emp.employeeID = @employeeid

        SELECT   
                employeeid
                ,name
                ,department
                ,[Time In]  = MIN(checkTime)
                ,[Time Out] = MAX(checkTime)
        FROM #MyReport
        GROUP BY  employeeid,name, department, CAST(checktime AS DATE)
    End
Else 
    Begin
        INSERT INTO #MyReport (employeeid,name, department, checkTime)
           select emp.EmpolyeeID, emp.Name,dep.DeptName,tm.checkTime 
                from TimeInOut tm
                left join Employee emp on emp.EmpolyeeId = tm.EmployeeId
                left join Department dep on dep.DeptID = emp.defaultDeptID
                where (DATEDIFF(s,@date1,tm.checktime) >=0 
                and DATEDIFF(s,@date2,tm.checktime)<=0) 
        SELECT   
                employeeid
                ,name
                ,department
                ,[Time In]  = MIN(checkTime)
                ,[Time Out] = MAX(checkTime)
        FROM #MyReport
        GROUP BY  employeeid,name, department, CAST(checktime AS DATE)
    End
END
Go

exec SEL_MyReport('639','05/01/2014','05/08/2014')
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for you to drop a temp table when your stored procedure starts.

Comment: Agree with Damien - In fact, I'm not sure you need use a #table at all - the `SELECT`s should suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a bit I would change - here is the code.

You will notice

- branching logic (if `@employeeid` > 0) has been replaced by a slightly more verbose `WHERE` clause
- no need for `#tables` as far as I can tell, the `SELECT` should suffice

Unfortunately, I do not have anything to test against, but you should understand the general impression of it.
Further, your date filtering seemed quite strange, so I assumed you may have meant something else - I could be mistaken. Either way, the way the date filtering is now done is [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEL_MyReport]
(
    @employeeid INT,
    @date1 DATETIME,
    @date2 DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT   emp.EmpolyeeID
            ,emp.Name
            ,dep.DeptName
            ,[Time In]  = MIN(tm.checkTime)
            ,[Time Out] = MAX(tm.checkTime)
    FROM TimeInOut  tm
    LEFT 
    JOIN Employee   emp on emp.EmpolyeeId =  tm.EmployeeId
    LEFT 
    JOIN Department dep on dep.DeptID =  emp.defaultDeptID
    WHERE tm.checktime >= @date1
    AND tm.checktime <= @date2
    /***********************************************************************************************************
    * I've assumed what you may be trying to express, above
    * You might also want to look at the BETWEEN() operator, remembering that it is inclusive in its behaviour
    *   (DATEDIFF(s,@date1,tm.checktime) >=0
    *   AND DATEDIFF(s,@date2,tm.checktime)<=0) 
    ***********************************************************************************************************/
    AND (emp.employeeID = @employeeid OR @employeeid <= 0)
    GROUP BY emp.EmpolyeeID, emp.name, dep.department, CAST(tm.checktime AS DATE)

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the very first step of your Stored Procedure attempts to drop a table, this will obviously result in an error if that table does not exist.

To work around this, make sure you check whether the table exists, before you drop it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyReport') IS NOT NULL DROP   
    TABLE #MyReport
```

Comment: I have one problem now when I execute the stored proc: exec SEL_Attendance_Report(639,'2014-05-01 00:00:00.000',getdate()) displays red underline under my stored proc and "639" displaying "incorrect syntax. Also getdate() has red underline displaying incorrect syntax –

Comment: When executing a stored procedure, don't use parentheses. So use something like this instead: `exec SEL_Attendance_Report 639, '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000', getdate()`